# How to set Firefox to open any/all links in a new tab?

Tags: firefox

As an example, when I click on a link from Google search result, I want them to open in a new tab as default (should work for every sites)

Is there any thing that I can change in the about:config?

Im using Firefox version 32.0.3

Thank you.

Comment: You can accomplish this by right-clicking on the link and selecting open in new tab.

Comment: Save a few clicks more by simply clicking the link with your mousewheel! Holding CTRL + Left Mouse Click works too.

Comment: May laptops don't have a mousewheel or middle mouse button. Even if I did, I'd still rather set this as the default left-click action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My recommendation is [Tab Mix Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-mix-plus/)

[image]

Control what action will open new tab, and if the new tab get the focus (select)
Open tabs from:

```
Bookmarks
Groups of bookmarks

When checked "Open All in Tabs" will open the bookmarks in new tabs, when unchecked the bookmarks will replace all tabs that are not locked or protected.
History
Address bar
Search bar

Middle-click or Control-click opens items in current tab
Only for bookmarks, history, links forced to open in new tab
```

Focus/Select tabs that open by these action:

```
Links
Diverted windows
Other applications
New tab commands
Duplicate Tab
Address bar
Search bar
Context menu search for
Bookmarks/History
Groups of bookmarks
```

Inverse Middle-click or Control-click focus for tabs opened by these action:

```
Links
Bookmarks/History, Address bar, Search bar
```

Answer (score 2):

Using an extension such as [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/), you can add a new script containing a bit of javascript.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        All Links in New Tab
// @namespace   *
// ==/UserScript==

(function(){
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "application/javascript";
    script.innerHTML = "$(function(){$('a').attr('target', '_blank');});";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
})();
```

The asterisk allows the script to be run on all websites.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox can't do this natively, however there are various plugins.

I recommend https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/open-link-in-new-tab/ because it has filters, so you can enable it only on specific domains

Comment: Alas, this seems like the correct answer. It would surely be very easy to add this feature.

Answer (score 1):

You want to open link in new tab in only one click.right? Have you tried mouse middle clicking(any websites links)? Why you need extensions or change in about:config?

Comment: Not sure if this applies to the original question, but some laptop trackpads (such as Mac) don't have middle click ability (with single click).

Comment: Yes, I also don't have a middle mouse button on my HP Pavilion laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox: Open Search Results in New Tab: http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/2136/firefox_open_search_results_new_tab/

1. In firefox, type about:config in the URL box
2. In the filter box, paste this text:

browser.search.openintab

3. Change the value to true by double-clicking the previous “false” text.